# Different Update Operation based on the condition [mongodb]

Tags: mongodb, nosql, crud

Hello stackoverflow community, 
I have the following documents format at mongoDB (simplifed for easy readability)

```
{
Company : "Alpha",
Products : 
[
{ Name : "Car",
SalesRecord : [ <Obj>]},
{Name: "Plane",
SalesRecord : [<Obj>]}
]
}
```

The update document is in same format but will only consist of *one product of company (which can be existing or or new) and one new sales record of that product* 
So How I want to do is

1. first I will find the documents by Company Name
2. Then I want to search in its products by Name keys,
3. if Product is **exists** then I want to push a record document to its SalesRecord
   Array. 
   if Product is **not exists** then I will add that new product document to
   the Products Array.

The sample query I have tried is as follows but the problem with this code is $push is not allowed in the $project State.

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
{Company:updateObj.Company},
    [
    {$project:{
        "Company": 1,
        "Products":{
        $switch :{
        branches:[
            {
                case:{$eq:['$Name',UpdateObj.Products[0].Name]},
                then: {$push:{'$Products.$.SalesRecord': UpdateObj.Products[0].SalesRecord[0}}
            },
            {
                case:{$ne:['$Name',UpdateObj.Products[0].Name]},
                then: {$push:{ Products:  UpdateObj.Products[0]}}
            }
   ]
    }}}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do the above by filtering each specific scenario and perform an update

```
db.collection(name).bulkWrite(
[
    {  /* first scenario is Both Company and the Product exists but update new Sales Object with same date`*/
        updateOne:{
            filter :{Company:chart[0].Company,'Products.Name' :chart[0].Products[0].Name},
            update : { $set:{
                "Products.$.SalesRecord.$[elem]": chart[0].Products[0].SalesRecord[0]
              }
            },
            arrayFilters: [{"elem.Date": chart[0].Products[0].SalesRecord[0].Date }]
        }
    },
    { /* second scenario is Both Company and the Products exists but no Sales object with same date exists */
   updateOne:{
            filter: {Company:chart[i].Company,'Products.Name': chart[i].Products[0].Name,'Products.SalesRecord.Date':{$ne:chart[0].Products[0].SalesRecord[0].Date}},
            update: {$push:{
                "Products.$.SalesRecord": chart[i].Products[0].SalesRecord[0]
            }         }            }
    },
    {
        /* Third scenario is Company exists but Product not exists */
        updateOne:{
            filter: {Company:chart[i].Company,'Products.Name':{$ne:chart[i].Products[0].Name}},
            update: {$push:{'Products': chart[i].Products[0]}}
        }
    },
    {
       /* fourth is if Company not exists */
        updateOne:{
        filter: {Company:chart[i].Company},
        update: {$setOnInsert:{'Products': chart[i].Products}},
        upsert: true
        }
    },
],
/* it needs to be ordered for not to be conflicted*/
{ordered:true})
```